# Configure mongomapper with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper

mongo.rb:1: uninitialized constant MongoMapper (NameError) that's the error i get on my  config/initializers/mongo.rb file.

i follwed the config tutorial from the http://www.mongodb.org website
that's the code in mongo.rb file

MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new('localhost', 27017)
MongoMapper.database = "#monmil-#{Rails.env}"

if defined?(PhusionPassenger)
   PhusionPassenger.on_event(:starting_worker_process) do |forked|
     MongoMapper.connection.connect if forked
   end
end

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initializer is no longer needed. That tutorial is outdated. Read the docs on http://mongomapper.com/